# Flutter: Parsing JSON array

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying out http requests from flutter to my backend.

My JSON is like this:

```
"_hits": {
    "Do8HpM3w0mh99SF": {
        "docid": "Do8HpM3w0mh99SF"
    },
    "HNLvkccTCIlmrcQ": {
        "docid": "HNLvkccTCIlmrcQ"
    },
    "QNSInDU2BJMF5SD": {
        "docid": "QNSInDU2BJMF5SD"
    },
    "UVDfRueZXIVCssk": {
        "docid": "UVDfRueZXIVCssk"
    },
    "Y9bNKklTr2Sg6Ai": {
        "docid": "Y9bNKklTr2Sg6Ai"
    },
    "kJgwwMbgF6PBwmMJSiKC": {
        "docid": "kJgwwMbgF6PBwmMJSiKC"
    },
    "py5MbGK11SsbXQ1": {
        "docid": "py5MbGK11SsbXQ1"
    }
}
```

My code to request:

```
Future<SearchResults> fetchJson() async {
      final response =
      await http.get('MyWebsite.com');

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
        // then parse the JSON.
        // print(response.body);
        return SearchResults.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
      } else {
        // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
        // then throw an exception.
        throw Exception('Failed to load request');
      }
    }
```

The Search Results Class:

```
class SearchResults {
  final String hits;

  SearchResults({this.hits});

  factory SearchResults.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return SearchResults(
      hits: json['_hits'],
    );
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

- Print the value of `docid` under the array of `_hits`

Coming From iOS Swift, this is very new to me, any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can custom backend response to correct json syntax ? Example _hits : [ { docid : xx } ]

Comment: @naijab.com the JSON is correct, i'm just showing a sample of it

Comment: Paste your JSON in https://app.quicktype.io/ and it will spit out the respective dart codes for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SearchResuts object is wrong as `_hits` is not a `String` but a `Map<String, dynamic>` to do it simple :

```
class SearchResults {
  Map<String, dynamic> hHits;

  SearchResults({this.hHits});

  SearchResults.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    hHits = json['_hits'];
  }
}
```

From here, you can iterate on your docids by getting a list of _hits elements like this :

```
print(searchResults.hHits.values.toList());
```

will print

```
[{docid: Do8HpM3w0mh99SF}, {docid: HNLvkccTCIlmrcQ}, {docid: QNSInDU2BJMF5SD}, {docid: UVDfRueZXIVCssk}, {docid: Y9bNKklTr2Sg6Ai}, {docid: kJgwwMbgF6PBwmMJSiKC}, {docid: py5MbGK11SsbXQ1}]
```